# Stack instance has no attribute " Something"

Tags: python

```
stack = Stack()

stack.isEmpty()
```

It gives:

> AttributeError: Stack instance has no attribute 'isEmpty'

And:

```
stack.checkBalanceSymbols("SomeString")
```

Gives:

> AttributeError: Stack instance has no attribute 'checkBalancedSymbols'

Whereas `stack.push(someData)`, `stack.pop()` and `stack.peek()` work fine.

```
from LLNode import Node

class Stack():

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.head = None
        self.data = None

    def push(self,data):
        temp = Node()
        temp.setData(data)
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def pop(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError
        else:
            temp = self.head.getData()
            self.head = self.head.getNext()
            return temp

    def peek(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError
        else:
            return self.head.getData()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def checkBalancedSymbols(self, input):
        symbolsStack = Stack()
        balanced = 0

        for symbol in input:
            if symbol in ["{","[","("]:
                symbolsStack.push(symbol)
            else:
                if symbolsStack.isEmpty():
                    balanced = 0
                    return balanced

                else:
                    topSymbol = symbolsStack.pop()

            if topSymbol != symbol:
                balanced = 0
                return balanced
            else:
                balanced = 1

        return balanced
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the indentation of `isEmpty` is such that it is not inside the `Stack` class?

Comment: No, both the functions isEmpty and checkBalancedSymbols are properly intended.

Comment: `checkBalanceSymbols != checkBalancedSymbols`. You are probably having problems with your camel casing.

Comment: That is just a typo I made while writing the question. Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. What version of Python are you running and on what OS?

Comment: I am running it on Idle Python 2.7.10 Shell, My OS has both the python2 and python3

Comment: Are you sure you use your class definition and not something else? Check `repr(Stack)` near `stack=Stack()` to check where the class comes from.

Comment: repr(Stack)
'<class stackLinkedListImplementation.Stack at 0x107e78b48>'     which is the same file.

Comment: Just noticed that the non-working functions are at the end of the class definition. Try moving them to the front. This changes nothing but maybe provokes an error or more information. (Still having a doubt about the indentation)

Comment: Where are you calling the `stack` stuff from? An IPython thing? Might be that you have to reload the module if you changed it while the shell was open.

Comment: I think that is an intention problem. check whether you have used tabs instead of spaces.